# 3D sound effects in space shooter game

Tags: c++, soundpool, stereo-3d

I am trying to implement a 3d sound system for my space shooter game . I have everything ready (playng sound with different volume in each side etc.) but i cant find the corrent formula to calculate the correct volume for each side.

The general idea is that every time the player(ship) kill's an enemie (the cammera is always on the top of the ship) , an explotion will be heard with the correct left and right volume . So if the enemie is right of the ship then the right channel will be heard more , same with the left case.

so i have

```
vector ship
vector enemie
```

and

```
playSound(left ? ,right ?)
```

How does game engines calculate the left and right channels?

Comment: how about imagining there are 2 objects left and right of the ship and then calculating the distance from those objects to the location of the enemy when it explodes. If the 2 distances are equal (the enemy is under or above your ship) then the channels should play equally loud. If not, the smallest distance (the side closer) could receive (smallerDistance/(biggerDistance/100))%

Comment: There is no sound in space, so a correct space game would be silent. :)

Comment: lol . Well its not exactly in space so sci fi friends will not get crazy with it .Like i do everytime i see this in a movie :)

Comment: Post your answer as an actual answer, please. Self-answering is encouraged. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solved it. I used something similar to what Ameoo said.

Here it is:

```
void Play3D(int id,vector3d ship,vector3d pos,float arenaWidth,float power)
{
    float disright=calculate_distance(ship.x+0.2f,ship.y,pos.x,pos.y);
    float disleft=calculate_distance(ship.x-0.2f,ship.y,pos.x,pos.y);
    sf.Play(2,1-disleft/arenaWidth*power,1-disright/arenaWidth*power);
}
```